# Ipad Cuts Off Text in Landscape Mode Even Without CSS Applied

Tags: css, ipad, screen-orientation

I'm currently trying to figure out why my layout is getting cut off on the right whenever it's viewed on an iPad (XCode emulator) in landscape orientation. Here's what's extra weird: even when I remove *all* css from the layout, I still run into the same issue. My guess is that it has something to do with my viewport settings or something else in my main layout file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no,maximum-scale=1.0">
        <title>MyCV - Levi Hackwith</title>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "/public/assets/css/app.css" />
        <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id = "app">
            {{{body}}}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here's the markup for the main content:

```
<section id = "sidebar">
    <section class = "contact-info">
        <div class = "avatar">
            <img src = "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{{item.gravatar}}
                 ?s=400">
        </div>
        <hr />
        <ul>
            <li>
                <span class = "label">Name</span>
                <span>
                    {{item.firstName}} {{item.lastName}}
                </span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span class = "label">Email</span>
                <span>
                    {{item.email}}
                </span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span class = "label">Location</span>
                <span>
                    {{item.addresses.home.city}},
                    {{item.addresses.home.state}}
                </span>
            </li>
            {{#if item.sites.length}}
            <li>
                {{#each item.sites}}
                <a href = "{{this.url}}" target = "_blank">
                    <i class ="fa-icon {{this.icon}} fa">&nbsp;</i>
                </a>
                {{/each}}
            </li>
            {{/if}}
        </ul>
    </section>
</section>
<section id = "main-content">
    {{#each item.workHistory}}
    <div class = "work-history-item">
        <div class = "company-info">
            <span class = "company-name">{{name}}</span>
            <time datetime= "{{startDate}}">
                {{#formatDate startDate 'MMMM YYYY'}}{{/formatDate}} -
                {{#if endDate}}
                {{#formatDate endDate 'MMMM YYYY'}}{{/formatDate}}
                {{else}}
                Present
                {{/if}}
            </time>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <p class = "work-description">
                    {{description}}
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class = "skill-list">
            {{#each skills}}
            <span class = "label">{{this.name}}</span>
            {{/each}}
        </div>
    </div>
    {{/each}}
</section>
```

A live demo of the app can be found here: http://digitalresume.herokuapp.com/users/54530e03c575dc86d61d22f8

In order to see the issue you'll need to strip out the css with dev tools.

Comment: Have you tried testing it without the mobile-specific meta tags to see if there's a conflict there? Do you have live code somewhere that I can take a look at?

Comment: I added a live link. When I remove the meta tags, the problem still persists

Comment: I don't have xcode because I'm on Windows, but I just popped that open in my iPad and it's rendering fine, for the most part (it's the first gen iPad).

Your portrait is stretched full height, and your tags are slightly overlapping. No cut off text though. Hopefully that means something's just off in your emulator.

Comment: Yeah, fine for me on iPad4 as well.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question is frustratingly simple: both the iPad emulator and the Chrome device emulator are broken and give you a false layout in Landscape mode. Sorry for wasting everyone's time.

Comment: I thought as much. Actual device testing is key. Best of luck!